# Intellij IDEA, code styling for javascript object, how to remove quotes when not necessary around key?

Tags: intellij-idea, styling, intellij-15

We would like to edit the javascript code styling in intellij to remove quotes around key within object when not necessary:

```
{
  "year": 2018,
  "month": 9,
  "day": 24,
  "startHours": 6,
  "startMinutes": 0,
}
```

should become

```
{
  year: 2018,
  month: 9,
  day: 24,
  startHours: 6,
  startMinutes: 0,
}
```

Using `CTRL+SHIFT+F` (Format code), is this possible ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using Format code. What you can do is `Select All` (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and then invoke the intention (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd>) `Unquote property names`.

Comment: I did (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)  after selecting the whole content of my file, and I do not have `Unquote property names` in my menu. I am using Idea Ultimate 2018

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fairly efficient solution. It does require mouse clicks on every key though so may not be appropriate for large scale replacements:

Double click on the key to highlight. Then press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

This copies the key, widens the selection to include the quotes and then pastes over the top